# How to install Chromium snap version 87

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium, flash, versions

I was wondering if there is a way to install Chromium snap version 87 along side with the current one. With `snap info chromium` you only get these versions:

channels: 
  latest/stable:    88.0.4324.96 2021-01-26 (1466) 142MB -
  latest/candidate: 88.0.4324.96 2021-01-26 (1466) 142MB -
  latest/beta:      89.0.4389.23 2021-01-30 (1470) 143MB -
  latest/edge:      90.0.4400.8  2021-01-30 (1471) 146MB -
installed:          88.0.4324.96            (1466) 142MB -



What if I needed both version 88 and 87 as I have some old devices that have  web management that needs Adobe Flash Player that has been dismissed since 12th January 2021.
Wanted to keep Chromium version 87, only to manage these old devices and use current Chromium version to surf the web.

Thanks for you help.
Carla

Comment: Possibly this can help: https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium#TOC-Downloading-old-builds-of-Chrome-Chromium